# IIS 7 sites, trabalhando com domainname.com não www.domainname.com. Problema de DNS?

Tags: iis, dns, iis-7

Eu tenho o meu nome de domínio registrado com [ASPHostPortal](http://asphostportal.com/) e apontando para o meu servidor IIS onde eu tenho um aplicativo ASP.net MVC implantado. Para conseguir isso eu simplesmente tem um registro de entrada que aponta para o endereço IP do meu servidor IIS.

O nome de ligação do meu aplicativo web IIS é domainname.com. Eu posso bater é apenas multa no navegador. No entanto, quando eu tentar acertar www.domainname.com ele atinge o website padrão do IIS. Como faço para obter tanto domainname.com e www.domainname.com para acertar minha aplicação web. Eu preciso de um especial Um registro ou entrada CNAME?

Além disso, eu gostaria * .domainname.com para bater meu aplicativo também. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso no DNS ou IIS?

Agradecemos antecipadamente

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ocorrer quando o seu `dominio.com` não foi adicionado como `A record` e o domínio `www` não foi adicionado como CNAME ([Canonical Name Record](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/58317?hl=pt-BR)).

Tente verificar em sua hospedagem se seu domínio está configurada desta forma:

```
domainname.com — NS — NS1.DOMINIO.COM.
domainname.com — NS — NS2.DOMINIO.COM.
domainname.com — A — ENDEREÇO IP
www — CNAME — domainname.com
```

Se preferir, pode verificar estes sites, para lhe ajudar a configurar:

- [Dominios com e sem www](http://www.pedrodias.net/how-to/dominios-com-e-sem-www)
- [Criar registos DNS em qualquer hospedagem](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Criar-registros-de-DNS-em-qualquer-provedor-de-hospedagem-de-DNS-para-o-Office-365-7b7b075d-79f9-4e37-8a9e-fb60c1d95166)